# Constructing Generalised Suffix Tree from a large set of strings

Tags: suffix-trees

Is there a published method to construct a generalised suffix tree from a large set of strings (~ 500 000) without the need of concatenating them?

I would like to use the resulting suffix tree for a pattern search problem.